# Externally cancelled subprocess in Camunda

Tags: camunda

The following subprocess in a BPM flow in Camunda appears as 'Cancelled activity instance'. Seems like it has been externally cancelled, but the flow itself continues after the subprocess close, even continue throw "External payment check finished" catch event, even when the event has not been launched.

My questions are:

1. **What could be the reasons for an externally cancelled subprocess in Camunda?**
2. **Why after the cancellation, the flow continues by catch event if the signar referenced has not be launched?**
3. **Do you think could be related with the usage of signals instead messages? Maybe I'm completely wrong but... Can this flow being getting signals from different instances?**

[image: Externally cancelled subprocess]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the usage of signals. Signals is like a broadcast; are listened for all active instances; in my case every time that "external payment check" was thrown, all the instances waiting for it was receiving the event and closing the subtask.

I have changed signals by 'escalation events' and everything goes fine!